# JsonResult - JSON object returning Empty value instead of null or undefined in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Please consider below as the reference code in which the above mentioned issue has occurred. Consider this as reference code and provide a solution for this.

This issue started occurring once i have updated the Newtonsoft.Json version from 9 to 10.

int relid = 10;

```
public JsonResult GetContactInfo()
        {
            List<Contact> _contactLst = new List<Contact>();
            if (relid > 0)
            {
                _contactLst = GetAllContactInfo();
                if (_contactLst != null && _contactLst.Count > 0)
                {
                    return Json(_contactLst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            return Json(_contactLst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
```

Comment: Are you sure about `relid > 0` is always true? and `_contactLst` is not null and has count greater 0 ?

Comment: Could you add reference to GetAllContactInfo() method? Seems like it's returning no data. Was it working fine before updating Newtonsoft version?

Comment: relid value always 10.  Before updating Newtonsoft version empty list is being returned

Comment: Looks like the **GetAllContactInfo** method sets the **_contactLst** null. The first return is skipped. And the second returns the **_contactLst**, which value is null.

Comment: I need empty list, but now here empty object is returned

Comment: why not to change the last line to:  
return Json(new List<Contact>(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
?

Comment: Even if we used in the above mentioned way, the empty object gets appended along with the list.  For example we are having 4 records which needs to be returned in view, the fifth record which is an empty object gets append.

Answer (score 0):

Unless and untill the GetAllContactInfo returns "null", the output of the above code will be either an empty or filled list due to intialization via "new List"

If you want the output to be null, you need to replace the initialization to be null and then set it up based on GetAllContactInfo output.

Comment: I need empty list, but now here empty object is returned

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult GetContactInfo()
        {
            List<Contact> _contactLst = new List<Contact>();
            if (relid > 0)
            {
                _contactLst = GetAllContactInfo();
                if (_contactLst.Any())
                {
                    return Json(_contactLst, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            return new List<Contact>();
}
```